# ASP.NET user control fails to render if registered with <%@ Register Assembly="" (as opposed to Src="")

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to create a user control and reference it on an aspx page. It works, but only if I reference the individual control, like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="schmapp" TagName="TestControl" Src="~/TestControl.ascx" %>
```

instead of referencing the whole namespace, like this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="UserControlTest" Namespace="UserControlTest" TagPrefix="app" %> <!-- doesn't work-->
```

I've done this many times yet it's been a while so I might be forgetting something basic. I refreshed my memory with a few tutorials and I think I'm doing the same steps.

I had this in the project I'm working on (.NET 3.5 under VS 2008) and I reproduced it step by step in a very basic project (.NET 4 under VS 2010) - [I uploaded it for reference purposes](http://www.bassheads.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/UserControlTest.rar).

I create a new asp.net web project, then Add -> New Item -> Web User Control, and then type some text into the ascx file (just to check if the control is being rendered). I then register the control and try to add it on the page. It works if it's referenced by Src attribute:

```
<schmapp:TestControl runat="server"/>
```

but not if the whole assembly is being referenced:

```
<app:TestControl runat="server" />
```

Now I can list the controls one by one but it's ugly and I don't want to accept defeat by something so simple, so I summon the might powers of teh internets to help.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct assembly and namespace? Your application has a name, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means for the application to have a name, but I checked the namespace and assembly name a number of times, and I copy-pasted them just in case.
This can also be seen on my test project that I linked to - [http://is.gd/VVtfcD](http://is.gd/VVtfcD)